# Why is this JQuery Ajax call not working in PhoneGap

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

i'm using PhoneGap with JQuery mobile ajax to retrieve some records from a database here's my code !! but unfortunately its not working 
can somebody tell me what's wrong

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cont').bind('pageshow', function () {
                       $.get('http://tech-tude.com/freedomwobas/getepisodes.php', function (data) {
                     $(this).find('div[data-role="content"]').append(data);
                 });
                    });
                    });

</script></head><body ><div data-role="content"></div>
```

Comment: its giving me a white page when i run the app

Comment: I assume your app resides in the same domain as the php referenced?

Comment: i didn't upload my app yet ! i'm doing it locally ! is that okay ?

Comment: If you're running a local http instance and you're trying to talk to a remote domain via an ajax call, it won't work. You're talking about cross-domain scripting, and for that you need to look into CORS or JSONP or things like reverse proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to (at least) wait for the device to be ready. Try this:

```
<script>
function onDeviceReady() {
    $('#cont').bind('pageshow', function () {
        $.get('http://tech-tude.com/freedomwobas/getepisodes.php', function (data) {
      $(this).find('div[data-role="content"]').append(data);
  });
     });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);       
});
</script></head><body ><div data-role="content"></div>
```